# How long should I wait for my PS3 to cool before playing again?

Tags: ps3

First of all, my PS3 is about 11 years old, I got it for Christmas 2009. It's fan starts whirring really loud and the PS3 makes cracking sounds after 1-3 hours of gameplay, sometimes I'm lucky and it lasts for 3 hours, other times, not so much.  When this happens, I quickly quit my games and turn off the PS3 and wait for maybe 20 minutes before playing again. Do you guys have better recommendations for how long to wait before starting to play again?

Comment: Until it's cool

Comment: Maybe you placed it in a airless compartment and it can't "breathe". If it has surfaces near his vents it could be aired in the right way

Comment: @IlJoker11 What is an airless compartment?

Comment: I meant that if you placed your ps3 in a place that is not aired the fans will be stressed, in particular when processes inside ps3 are heavier

Answer (score 3):

You are free to wait 5 minutes or more depending on the ambient temperature near the console, but for a console that has more than 10 years ill recommend swapping the thermal paste in RSX and CELL-BE chips, and if is one of the Fat models or a Slim 20XX, a [change of capacitors](https://www.psx-place.com/threads/tutorial-research-nec-tokin-capacitors-replacement-ylod-fix.25260/) so you don't get the Yellow Light of Death in the future.